# How is the usage of constructors an implementation of data-hiding?

Tags: c++, data-hiding

I know what constructors are used for, and kinda know what data hiding means.... found **absolutely no link**  among the two (im a dimwit, sedd).... please help?

Comment: Then put that answer down in your homework. What brings you to the conclusion that the two are related in the first place?

Comment: my sensei said so..... and i didn't buy it... XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have argued that ctors can be used as a form of RAII. Essentially we can initialise an internal (private) variable via a constructor, and that variable can now be made to be inaccessible outside of the class.

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(int i)
    : m_i(i) {} //< only place we init variable

private:
  int m_i; //< we cannot access this var
};
```

Comment: I don't really see what does RAII has to do with all this. After all, there are no **resources** in your example.

Comment: hmm.... but only when we use access specifiers (which were *made* to implement data hiding, r8?)